# Insert data to multiple tables in spring jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I have two tables, **user** and **transaction**. Where `one user` can have `many transactions`. So, everytime I `create new user`, they automatically make `new transaction` and the `transaction type` is **SEND MONEY**. But I don't understand how to write it in Spring JPA. Please take a look on my code and help me.

User.java

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "money")
    private int money;
    
    //Getter Setter Constructor
}
```

Transaction.java

```js
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_trans")
    private long id_trans;

    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private long id_user;

    @Column(name = "transaction_date")
    private Timestamp transaction_date;

    @Column(name = "type") //Default set as "SEND MONEY"
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "trans_money") //From money in User.class
    private int trans_money;


    //Getter Setter Constructor
}
```

I know I should do something in my **UserDAO.java**, but I still don't know how to send data from body and split(?) it into two object (`user` and `transaction`, so I can persist it in **UserDAO**).

Comment: did you get a chance to try the answers?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to write the relationship between User and Transaction.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "money")
    private int money;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Transaction> transactions = new HashSet<>();
    
    //Getter Setter Constructor
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_trans")
    private long id_trans;

    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private long id_user;

    @Column(name = "transaction_date")
    private Timestamp transaction_date;

    @Column(name = "type") //Default set as "SEND MONEY"
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "trans_money") //From money in User.class
    private int trans_money;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id")
    private User user;

    //Getter Setter Constructor
}
```

Then you have to create the JPA repository interface for the User

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository <User, Long> {
}
```

Then in a service, you can do the following

```
@Service
public class UserService {
    private UserRepo userRepo;

    @Autowired
    MealService(UserRepo userRepo){
        this.userRepo = userRepo;
    }

    public void CreateNewUser(){
        User user = new User();
        // set its values

        Transaction transaction = new Transaction();
        transaction.setType("SEND MONEY");
        // set other values

        user.getTransactions().add(transaction);

        userRepo.save(user);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the `@Entity` classes mentioned it seems to me that there exists an `@ManyToOne` association between `Transaction` and `User` which is not captured in the entity relationship modeling/mapping.

Please consider modeling that in your `Transaction` entity as follows,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id_trans")
    private long id_trans;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.MERGE}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "transaction_date")
    private Timestamp transaction_date;

    @Column(name = "type") //Default set as "SEND MONEY"
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "trans_money") //From money in User.class
    private int trans_money;


    //Getter Setter Constructor
}
```

Once you do that you can create a JPA repository class for `Transaction` and `User` and simply use the `save` method to do what you want in a transaction after constructing your instances. More on transactions in Spring Data JPA [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#transactions)

```
public interface TransactionRepository extends JpaRepository<Transaction, Long> {
}
```